# Pandas: Defining dataframe column based on return of a function that requires column value as input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with `columns = ["UID", ... "reviewText"]`. I'm trying to add a column to a dataframe that should analyse the reviewText in another column on it's AFINN score. I'm using the afinn.score from the afinn package.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from afinn import Afinn
afn = Afinn()

df_analysis = pd.read_csv(data)

df_analysis["AFINN"] = afn.score(str(df_analysis["reviewText"]))
```

The afn.score function works fine if I give it some string, but when I look at the dataframe, the entire column is 0. Is there something I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I've just realised that converting it to a string is not correct. I've now tried the following:

```
df_analysis["AFINN"] = afn.score(df_analysis["actualText"].to_string())
```

But that gives me the Afinn score of all the reviews combined. Is there a way to only take one row at a time, convert it to a string and pass it to the afn.score function, which will then return the afinn value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pandas.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html).

```
import pandas as pd
from afinn import Afinn

afn = Afinn()

df_analysis = pd.read_csv(data)

df_analysis["AFINN"] = df_analysis["reviewText"].apply(lambda x: afn.score(str(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
    df_analysis["AFINN"] = df_analysis["reviewText"].map(afn.score)
```

This uses the function on each value in the DF column. Your original code tried to apply the function to the whole column.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the entire column as a single string and is calculating the score for the entire column, instead of a single row or string.

You can use the apply() method to review each text individually.

```
df_analysis["AFINN"] = df_analysis["reviewText"].apply(afn.score)
```